# Call JQuery function in div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my html files is invisible element:

```
<div class="field">
     <div id="warring" style="color:red; display:none;">
        warrning text
     </div>
</div>
```

and function:

```
function showStepsWarrning(){
  $('warring').show();
}
```

I need to call this function in `if statement` from option component, tried to do this by:

```
<option #if(${show.value}) window["showStepsWarrning"]()#end>
  $!project.key.name
</option>
```

but `window["showStepsWarrning"]()` doesn't work.

How is it posisble to solve my problem?

Comment: Try placing the function inside a `<script>` tag and place the `<script>` tag inside the element.

Comment: @WaisKamal: No, there's no need to do that, nor would it make the code above work.

Comment: What is that template notation at the end, and (more importantly) what does the **browser** actually see?

Comment: it is in <script> but still doesnt work

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I use firefox

Comment: Are you wrapping your function definition for `showStepsWarrning` in an IIFE or other function? This would cause it to not be attached to the window object. Maybe setting it on `window` directly will help ie `window.showStepsWarrning = function(){ $('#warring').show(); }`  Besides this probably need to know more about whatever templating engine/framework you're using and wher ethings like `show.value` is defined etc.... and double check that `$!project.key.name` is outputting as intended

Comment: @PaulGerbert: Firefox has nothing whatsoever to do with the question I asked. What is pre-processing the `<option #if(${show.value}) window["showStepsWarrning"]()#end>$!project.key.name</option>` template? (As that's not HTML.)

Comment: yes that's not html, this is Velocity

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `#` for selecting the element by id. 
your code shoule be :

```
function showStepsWarrning(){
    $('#warring').show();
}
```

Comment: it did not help

Comment: Check the browser inspector, are you getting any kind of error in console?

Comment: @PaulGerbert can you please anser  T.J. Crowder question. In which language/ template language you are writing the if condition code?

Comment: if statement is in Velocity

Comment: Yes @T.J.Crowder, I got it. It was my misunderstanding also. thanks for pointing out. I'll keep it in mind for future.

Comment: @PaulGerbert: Yes. Your element has the `id` "warring", and that's how you select an element with that ID (and of course, there can be only one element with that ID).

Comment: @tejashsoni111: My comment wasn't directed at *you* (other than to let you know that at least one other person -- me -- thinks this was a good answer). It was directed at whoever downvoted the answer.

Comment: unfortunately there is only one element with id="warring" and code doesn't work

Comment: @PaulGerbert as per my understanding if you want to call function on selection of specific option then you can do something like this : [https://jsfiddle.net/rkrekdrr/](https://jsfiddle.net/rkrekdrr/) . This is just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to achieve this.  I am calling **showStepsWarrnings()** on selection of options and changing the alert colour accordingly. http://codepen.io/shivk/pen/ENqwRP

```js
function showStepsWarrning1(){
  $('#warring').show();
  $("#warring").css("color", "red");

}

function showStepsWarrning2(){
  $('#warring').show();
  $("#warring").css("color", "blue");
}

function showStepsWarrning3(){
  $('#warring').show();
  $("#warring").css("color", "green");
}




var options = [{"value" : "1",
                "display" : "One",
                "fn" : function() { console.log("One clicked");alert("one");}
               },
               {"value" : "2",
                "display" : "Two",
                "fn" : function() { console.log($(this).val() +  " clicked"); showStepsWarrning1();}
               },
               {"value" : "3",
                "display" : "Three",
                "fn" : function() { console.log("Three clicked");showStepsWarrning2(); }
               },
               {"value" : "4",
                "display" : "Four",
                "fn" : function() { console.log("Four clicked");  showStepsWarrning3();}
               }];

var $select = $("select").on("click keyup", function() {
    var opt = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
    $(opt).data("fn").call(opt);
});

$.each(options, function(i, val) {
    $select.append(
        $("<option/>").attr("value", val.value)
                      .text(val.display)
                      .data("fn", val.fn)
    );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select></select>


<div class="field">
     <div id="warring" style="color:red; display:none;">warrning text</div>
</div>
```